# Оптимизация присваивания переменной полученной из БД Entity Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq

Привет ребята.
Есть такой код:

```
                var query = context.stores
                               .Where(a => a.Adress == adr)
                               .Where(r => r.repr.initials == repr)
                               .Where(r=> r.region.Name == reg).ToList();
                var reprQue = context.reps
                                     .Where(r => r.initials == repr).ToList();
                query[0].repr = reprQue[0];
                context.SaveChanges();
```

В нём я заменяю "объект" в БД. Привязанный элемент из другой таблицы.
Если я заведомо уверен, что объект там будет один как мне сделать присваивание без помощи превращения запроса в List?
Вижу примерно такой способ:
query[0].repr = (Model.Store)reprQue;
но может есть что-нибудь более красивое для превращения результата запроса в конкретный объект?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените `.ToList()` на `.Single()` и уберите `[0]`